# how to use has_one relation in rails without assigning a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The situation I am thinking about is as follows. For each user in my site, I want to assign a profile picture. So I would use the following code
  Model user
   has_one :profile_pic, :classname =>'pic'
  end 
  But I don't want to give every pic object a foreign key user_id, because many pictures are not associated with a user at all. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In my view you can use has_one association if you don't wanna store those multiple profile pictures of your user and update each time the picture is updated.

On the other hand if you are thinking to store all the profile photos uploaded by your user then may be you make a albums model where you store your users profile pictures. use

```
has_many :photos, :through => :albums
```

and show the first image to user.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

```
class User
  belongs_to :profile_pic, :classname => 'Pic'
end
```

and have a `profile_pic_id` in your `users` table. Makes sense.

Don't worry about users `belonging_to` pictures. It only means that the key is stored in this object's table, not in the other object's table.